# What do I use to display CSV data as a chart?

Tags: xml, perl, excel, csv, charts

I have a set of data stored in text files, which I have now via Perl put into a CSV file. The data in question now needs to be displayed in a chart.

What suggestions do you have for doing this? XML was suggested, but XML can't put the data into a chart itself.

Ideally what would happen is: the data would be decoded from the text file, put into an Excel spreadsheet and displayed as a chart, all with one bit of code, as there are many of these text files with data in them.

Perl, XML, C, C++, C# and VB are all available to use.

Comment: dont know if this is what you are looking for http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php

Comment: I have edited the question to exchanged the word *graph* with *chart* because *graph* also has a different meaning that does not apply here. If you do not agree, you can easily undo this. – We use [`Chart::OFC2`](http://p3rl.org/Chart::OFC2) at work. I recommend you avoid proprietary technologies like Flash and Excel if you can help it, most of the time output in standard formats like SVG and PNG is good enough. Search CPAN for appropriate [chart modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=chart).

Comment: Ok, well due to various reasons downloading new modules will be very complicated, so I'm going for using OLE (which I already have).Now all that is left is to understand OLE well enough to work out how to create a new Excel document and be able to save it...

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-to-chart github project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl, you can use the `Win32::OLE` module to automate placing the data in an Excel spreadsheet and displaying it in a chart.

You will need to be familiar with the OLE library though in order to understand what methods/properties to call and set.

Comment: I don't suppose you know what the {ChartType} is for a scatter chart?

Comment: @Andy : The OLE library is documented in the Object Browser. Go into VBA mode (within Excel) and hit `F2`.

Answer (score 9):

[`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) is an excellent CPAN module for creating Excel files in Perl.

In particular take a look at [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Chart.pm) which allows you to create charts within the excel file.

Comment: Good suggestion. One minor addition to it: The [Excel::Writer::XLSX charts](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Chart.pm) are a better option these days. They include all the features of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel but with additional chart types and features. See also the [Excel::Writer::XLSX chart examples](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example:_chart_area.pl)

Answer (score 2):

For my use, I have found [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/GD%3a%3aGraph) to be a decent option for generating charts in PNG format. You can also use [Chart::Gnuplot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Chart%3a%3aGnuplot).

I also have [an example of creating a chart in an Excel document using Win32::OLE](http://www.unur.com/comp/ppp/perl-win32-ole-excel-ex1.html).

Answer (score 2):

How about [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info)? You can send the data and commands to it through STDIN, which works in Perl very well or there are some [libraries](http://lug.fh-swf.de/perl/GnuplotIF.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Chart::Clicker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Chart%3a%3aClicker) is good. Its output is less pixelated than that of GD::Graph, and it supports transparent overlapping parts.